# Extreme Cosplay Quest Fail

Tags: the-witcher-3

I talked to some guy on the road and started a quest called Extreme Cosplay. I told him to come with me and then went to explore the estate. I smashed open the door, went inside, and then went on Google to make sure the quest wasn't too long (I wanted to get on with the Wight quest already). I found out that it was supposedly difficult unless you were overleveled, so I left, finished with the Wight, and thought I'd try finishing Extreme Cosplay. When I go up to the front door that I smashed open earlier though, it's closed and there's a note on it that says "Danger!" and whenever I read it the quest fails.

The last save before when I left that quest hanging was before I started the Blood and Wine DLC questline, so I can't revert saves. Is there any way for me to complete the quest, or am I doomed to fail it now that I put it off?

Comment: This seems to be a known bug that many players have faced. Once initiated, you can not back out of the quest and return later.

Comment: Damn, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same bug.

Comment: @intA Nope -- just had to give up on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Saddly, this quest will auto-fail shortly after you've started it if you don't immediately finish it.

1) When you 1st see these guys on the side of the road, pass 'em by.  If you do make the mistake of starting the quest, reload from your last save.  On the bright side, a nice yellow exclamation mark will stay on your map telling you it's still there for you to start.

2) The level of this quest (at least during my last NG+ play through) is identical to the required level to wear Grand Master Witcher armor.  This way you know when you're at least the right level.

3) The Elemental Damage during this quest is *insane*.  May I recommend Maxing out your Elemental Resistance by wearing Grand Master Cat school Armor and Boots, Grand Master Wolf school Pants and Gloves and perhaps round it out with some Elemental Resistance Runes if you've got [the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone](/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone) DLC.

By the time you've collected and equiped this gear, you'll have both the level & resistance required to make this quest *much* easier.